# Tick "Build" in Visual Studio's Configuration Manager for projects programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, build, automation, configurationmanager

I'm trying to set the "Build" Tick Boxes in Visual Studio's Configuration Manager by some sort of script.

This is for different "project build modes", so that I can swap between having some projects build or not depending on what I'm currently working on. I dislike having to do things manually, so I'm trying to make it work by way of an automatic script or program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following C# script for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        this.DTE = DTE;

        SetShouldBuild(@"ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj", true);
    }

    void SetShouldBuild(string project, bool shouldBuild)
    {
        EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution2;
        EnvDTE80.SolutionBuild2 solutionBuild2;
        EnvDTE.SolutionContexts solutionContexts;

        solution2 = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)DTE.Solution;
        solutionBuild2 = (EnvDTE80.SolutionBuild2)solution2.SolutionBuild;

        foreach (EnvDTE80.SolutionConfiguration2 solutionConfiguration2 in solutionBuild2.SolutionConfigurations)
        {
            solutionContexts = solutionConfiguration2.SolutionContexts;
            foreach (EnvDTE.SolutionContext solutionContext in solutionContexts)
            {
                if (solutionContext.ProjectName == project)
                    solutionContext.ShouldBuild = shouldBuild;
            }
        }
    }

    EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
}
```

Add multiple **SetShouldBuild** calls to "tick" build for several projects at once.

Comment: So if I understand this right, this is using EnvDTE80, and setting the ShouldBuild of the solution context can control the tickbox?

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose It uses Visual Studio SDK and changes internal solution build settings.